# Menu and search area inline issue

Tags: php, html, css

The site looks horrible because the search area and the menu are not in the same line. Can anyone please guide me how I can make this search area inline with the menu? Please guide. Thanks.
My site: http://www.amp.com.pk/

```
<header id="branding" role="banner">

    <div class="header-wrapper">
    <a href="<?php home_url(); ?>"><img style="width:750px;" src="http://www.amp.com.pk/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/headeramp.png"></a>
        <hgroup>

            <h1 onClick="location.href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>'" id="site-title"><span><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h1>

            <h2 id="site-description">Adnan Malik Productions</h2>

            <h2 id="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>

        </hgroup>







        <?php

            // Has the text been hidden?

            if ( 'blank' == get_header_textcolor() ) :

        ?>

            <div class="only-search<?php if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?> with-image<?php endif; ?>">

            <?php get_search_form(); ?>

            </div>

        <?php

            else :

        ?>

            <?php get_search_form(); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>



        <nav id="access" role="navigation">



            <?php /*  Allow screen readers / text browsers to skip the navigation menu and get right to the good stuff. */ ?>

            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to primary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>

            <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to secondary content', 'twentyeleven' ); ?></a></div>

            <?php /* Our navigation menu.  If one isn't filled out, wp_nav_menu falls back to wp_page_menu. The menu assiged to the primary position is the one used. If none is assigned, the menu with the lowest ID is used. */ ?>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>

        </nav><!-- #access -->

    </div>



</header><!-- #branding -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**EDIT**

Remove `position:absolute` from `.only-search`

**EDIT #2**

Set `margin-top:0` to `#branding #s`

Set `position: relative` to `#access` and place inside the search element.
Now, give:

```
div.only-search {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0
}
```

Or set:

```
#searchform #s {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thought it solved the problem but it moved my menu to too below than it was before.

Answer (score 0):

So have a look at this : 
1. Move the the div with the search box like this to the ul element.

```
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu"><li></li>...
     <div class="only-search">
             <form method="get" id="searchform" action="http://www.amp.com.pk/">
                <input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search">
            </form>
         </div>
```

and edit the css like this if you want the searchbox is on the same line as the menu :

```
#branding #searchform {
/* clear: left; */
}
```

if you want that it floats to the next row :

```
  .one-column #branding #searchform {
    right: 40px;
    top: 4em;
    /* float: right; */
    }
    www.amp.com.pk/media="all"
    #branding #searchform {
    clear: left;
    }
```